# Intercept Http requests to add JWT token and handle token refresh on 401 error, infinite loop of requests

Tags: angular

I have written the below interceptor which is working mostly as expected, apart from once my refresh token has expired, it gets stuck in a loop or re-requesting an updated access token with the expired refresh token and I can't figure out why?

My interceptor to Http requests looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private inject: Injector){}   
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let userService = this.inject.get(UserService)
        let authReq = request;
        authReq = this.AddTokenHeader(request, userService.getToken())
        return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
            catchError(errordata => {
                if(errordata.status === 401){
                    //401 status error, the access token needs refreshing.
                    return this.handleRefreshToken(request, next)
                }
            return throwError(() => errordata)
            })
        )
    } 

    AddTokenHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: any){
        return request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token)})
    }

    handleRefreshToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
        let userService = this.inject.get(UserService)
        return userService.GenerateRefreshToken().pipe(
            switchMap((data:any) => {
                userService.updateAccessToken(data)
                return next.handle(this.AddTokenHeader(request, localStorage.getItem('accessToken')))
            }),
            catchError(errordata => {
                userService.logout()
                return throwError(() => errordata)
            })
        )
    }
}
```

And the UserService contains this among other functions, but I think this is the only one really relevant.

```
public GenerateRefreshToken(){
        return this.http.post(this.djangoPath+'/api/token/refresh/', JSON.stringify({"refresh": localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')}), this.httpOptions) 
    }
```

I thought the catchError in the handleRefreshToken function would deal with the refresh token being expired and then result to logging out the user to force religion to generate a new refresh token, but clearly I am wrong. I am just getting repeated 401 responses from the refresh call as the token is expired. It works fine while the refresh token is valid.

Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong? The backend is Django/DRF/SimpleJWT.

Finally, Merry Christmas to anybody who chooses to celebrate it.

Comment: I think this site has the answer you're looking, see the function private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler),   https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-12-refresh-token/

Comment: try adding console.log into your code to see the data it's getting and the code flow. That will help you debug easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You didn't mention what `updateAccessToken` method does, but I believe it's saving the token to the `localStorage`)

I believe the problem is that - `userService.GenerateRefreshToken()` method is also intercepted by this interceptor, so any time you get to `catchError` you call this function which goes into this interceptor again and calls this function - and here is the loop...

what you can do is exclude this route from being intercepted - wrap your code with this condition:

```
if(req.url.includes('/api/token/refresh/')) {
   // only for this route skip interceptor logic
   return next();
}
```

good luck :)

Comment: Correct in your assumption of what updateAccessToken does, it just saves the new access token from the refresh to localStorage.

Comment: I have adjusted to include the below in the intercept, which is only slightly different but follows the same logic I believe. `if(authReq.url.includes('/api/token/refresh/')) {
            // only for this route skip interceptor logic
            return next.handle(authReq);
         }` Thankyou very much for your help!